# Is $2^\kappa$ regular if $\kappa$ is regular?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm reading Jech's Set Theory and I'm struggling with a remark he makes when speaking about cardinal exponentiation without GCH.

Theorem 5.16 says that without GCH the following hold:

> (i) If $\kappa < \lambda$ then $2^\kappa \leq 2^\lambda$.
>
> (ii) $ \mathrm{cf} \; 2^\kappa > \kappa.$
>
> (iii) If $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal then $2^\kappa = (2^{<\kappa})^{\mathrm{cf} \; \kappa}$.

After the statement of the theorem Jech remarks:

> For regular cardinals, the only conditions Theorem 5.16 places on the continuum function are $2^\kappa > \kappa$ and $2^\kappa \leq 2^\lambda$ if $\kappa < \lambda$.

Now, I'm having trouble understanding the first condition that $2^\kappa > \kappa$. My suspicion is that it follows from (ii) via the statement in the title of the question, i.e.

> If $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, so is $2^\kappa$.

With GCH we would have $2^\kappa = \kappa^+$ and as successor cardinal $\kappa^+$ is always regular. But without GCH I have no idea how to prove this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $2^\kappa \gt \kappa$ is Cantor's theorem, proven by the diagonalization argument.  This is independent of regularity.

Comment: Thanks! How could I overlook that ...

Comment: Also note that $cf(\lambda)\le\lambda$, so even in the singular case, Konig’s theorem directly implies Cantor’s (and gives *more* information in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not necessarily the case. König's theorem says that the cofinality of $2^\kappa$ is at least $\kappa^+$, but nothing about it being regular.

Indeed, $2^{\aleph_0}$ could be $\aleph_{\omega_1}$, and Easton's theorem implies that it is consistent with $\sf ZFC$ that if $\kappa$ is regular, then $2^\kappa=\aleph_{\kappa^+}$, which is always singular.

Comment: Shouldn't that say the cofinality of $2^{\kappa}$ is at least $\kappa^+$?

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction!